# Scroll to id on page from link angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a back button in my app that needs to go back to the previous page, but to a specific point on that page. I have the router links and id's setup and the hash shows in the URL, but it just doesn't want to move down the page.

My button looks like this

```
<button
  type="button"
  kendoButton
  [primary]="true"
  class="warn"
  [routerLink]="['/thisIs/a/link']"
  fragment="{{dynamicId}}"
  id="{{dynamicId}}">
  Back
</button>
```

and then on the other page my id's look like this

```
<div class='row' id="one">
One
</div>

<div class='row' id="two">
Two
</div>

<div class='row' id="three">
Three
</div>
```

And the URL is showing
/thisIs/a/link#one

Any ideas? I can't find anything when searching why it's not scrolling to the divs

Comment: You have to capture route change event and get the hash and scroll to that manually. Check this: https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-detecting-route-changes/

Comment: @maverickosama92, I am doing that though. It is going to the right page, just not the right spot on the page

Comment: can you please replicate your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/angular so that we understand your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the scrolling yourself, the browser doesn't automatically do that for you. since you are using `angularjs` you can focus on a specific element by `$window.scrollTo(0, angular.element('myelement').offsetTop);`

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  if (fromStat == statContainingBackButton && toState === statContainingMyElement) {
    $window.scrollTo(0, angular.element('myelement').offsetTop);
  }
});
```

Comment: But where would this go? Does this need to go in the button routing?

Comment: Also, since the id is in the URL shouldn't it go to the matching point on the page. I've done that with just HTML before.

Comment: I am still confused. Where would I put that since the router link and the fragment are within the button? I can't put it at the top of the page because it's not always going to have the hash to go to

Comment: where are you rendering the view? where ever the id exists or which ever controller renders the view with the id you should put this code there

Comment: I can't put it in the  ngOnInit()  of the controller because it's not always going to have a hash to go to. Plus how would I get the hash down from the URL? And I can't get the window to properly import no matter what I do or how I put it